# Can Mathematica solve functional equations with nested variable?

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

First, inline free form input can solve these equations:

[image]

[image]

But it seems no native Mathematica function can solve these, there is even an error page for equations of this form (nestdv).

Now my question is: Is this a function implemented only in Wolfram Alpha but not Mathematica? How can we solve these equations in Mathematica (natively)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't seem there is a one line solution but we can adapt W|A to give a result similar to `DSolve` and friends.

```
fSolve[eq_Equal] := fSolve @ ToString@eq;

fSolve[eq_String] := Values[ WolframAlpha[
   "solve " <> eq, {"SolutionAsAFunctionalEquation", "FormulaData"}
 ]
] /. Hold[Equal[f_, d_]] :> f -> d /. {
   Subscript[\[ScriptC], n_] :> C[n], \[ScriptC] -> C[0]
}
```

---

```
fSolve["f[f[x]] == f[1 + x]"]
```

> ```
> {f[x] -> 1 + x}
> ```

```
fSolve[f[f[x]] == x]
```

> ```
> {{
>   f[x] -> -x + C[0], 
>   f[x] -> C[0]/x, 
>   f[x] -> (-x + C[1])/(1 + x C[2]),
>   f[x] -> 1/2 (x C[1] + Sqrt[-4 x^2 + C[1]^2 + C[2]]), 
>   f[x] -> (-x^3 + C[0])^(1/3)
> }}
> ```