# How to solve an equation with a nested function

Tags: equation-solving

I have the equation

```
f[f[x]] == 28 + 9 x
```

How can I solve this for `f[x]`? I note that [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114210/can-mathematica-solve-functional-equations-with-nested-variable) relates to the topic, but **Wolfram|Alpha** doesn't work for my equation. So is there a method that can do it?

Comment: Try `WolframAlpha["f[f[x]]==28+9*x solve for x"]`

Comment: @Louis I want to get `f[x]` but `x`. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the link you provided in your question shows, there is no unique solution. For example (and illustration), assuming a form (linear function) yields 2 solutions:

```
lhs = CoefficientRules[Nest[a # + b &, x, 2], x]
rhs = CoefficientRules[28 + 9 x, x]
{f1, f2} = 
 a # + b & /. 
  Solve[{({1} /. lhs) == ({1} /. rhs), ({0} /. lhs) == ({0} /. rhs)}, {a, b}]
```

yields:

> `{-3 #1 - 14 &, 3 #1 + 7 &}`

Testing:

```
Simplify[Nest[f1, x, 2]]
Simplify[Nest[f2, x, 2]]
```

Both yield

> `28 + 9 x`

Comment: good solution..

Comment: `SolveAlways` or `Solve` with `ForAll` could be used to avoid having to split the equation into one for each coefficient.

Answer (score 5):

It is interesting to see if there are some slightly more general solutions.  For example, by assuming that the function has a fixed point for some unknown value `c` we can do a series expansion to various orders:

```
f[f[x]] == 28 + 9 x
Series[%, {x, c, 6}]
% //. f[c] -> c
LogicalExpand[%]
Reduce[%]
FullSimplify[%]
Solve[%]
```

which gives

$\left\{\left\{c\to -\frac{7}{2},f'\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to -3,f''\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(3)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(4)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(5)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(6)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0\right\},\left\{c\to -\frac{7}{2},f'\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 3,f''\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(3)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(4)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(5)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0,f^{(6)}\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right)\to 0\right\}\right\}$

This obviously supports the idea that the only analytic functions with a fixed point satisfying the equation are linear.

Comment: I think the restriction to functions with fixed points can be relaxed by taking the series of `f[f[f[x]]]`: `28 + 9f[x] == f[28+9x]` about `x=-7/2`.

Comment: That's an interesting point.  You show that there aren't any other analytic solutions

Comment: A harder problem is if there are non-analytic solutions, and how to construct one. I believe there are piecewise solutions from the 2 possible analytic functions f1 and f2, but it's not trivial. My idea was to start with the infinite sequence from forward and backward recursion over f1 from some point other than x=-7/2, then repeat from all x from which this sequence can be reached by f2(x) etc. I think the set of points from these sequences is countable, so let f be f1 if x is from this set and f2 otherwise. Is there a simpler answer? I hesitate to post as this is more math than Mathematica.

Comment: @obsolesced I'd be interested to see it. If you can give a procedure for generating such a sequence in Mathematica it would be a reasonable post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt to construct a non-analytic solution. The idea is to use one of the analytic solutions in the accepted answer when `x` belongs to a set of points reachable through successive application of either analytic solution or their inverses, and the other solution otherwise. This set must not be equal the set of reals, otherwise the solution just reduces to one of the analytic solutions. I thought of a way to show this set is countable, and therefore can't be equal the real set, but realized it's easier to show by counterexample after finding the set.

I start with a couple of observations to facilitate finding this set. The first is the convenient commutativity of `f1` and `f2`:

```
Simplify[f1[f2[x]] == f2[f1[x]]]
```

which means any sequence of `f1` and `f2` is equivalent to one with the same total number `n1` and `n2` of `f1` and `f2` calls respectively, e.g. `n1` `f1` calls followed by `n2` `f2` calls. This commutativity also implies the inverses are commutative, and sequences of `InverseFunction[f1]` and `InverseFunction[f2]` can be similarly ordered.

The second is the nth application of `f1` or `f2` is the sum of a constant term, which is a geometric series of length n, and a linear term, which is the nth term in another geometric series. These terms can be computed by hand, but Mathematica gives a convenient way to do so:

```
s1[x_]=FindSequenceFunction[NestList[f1,x,3]];
s2[x_]=FindSequenceFunction[NestList[f2,x,3]];
```

It can be shown the nth application of `InverseFunction[f1]` or `InverseFunction[f2]` to `x` is equal `s1[x][-n]` or `s2[x][-n]` respectively.

With these results, the set of points that can be reached from `x0` satisfies:

```
criteria = Simplify[Reduce[{s2[s1[x][n1]][n2] == x0}, {n1, n2}], 
                    Assumptions -> {{n1, n2} \[Element] Integers, {x, x0} \[Element] Reals}]
```

> $$
> \left(x=-\frac{7}{2}\land \text{x0}=-\frac{7}{2}\right)\lor \left(c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land 2 x+7\neq 0\land 2 \text{x0}+7\neq 0\land \\
> \log (3) (\text{n1}+\text{n2})-2 i \pi  c_1=\log \left(-\frac{9 (-1)^{\text{n1}} (2 \text{x0}+7)}{2 x+7}\right)\right)
> $$

Unless `x0` is the fixed point `-7/2`, we can reach `x` if there are integers `n1` and `n2` satisfying this equation.

Here, the only imaginary terms are $2i\pi c_1$ and from the `log` on the right-hand side. Since `x` and `x0` are real, the imaginary part of the `log` can only be 0 or $i\pi$. The former requires $c_1=0$, while the latter cannot be satisfied for any $c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$. We can therefore set $c_1=0$.

Moreover, given `x` and `x0`, there are only two possibilities for the `log`, one with `n1` even, and one with `n1` odd. Regardless of whether `n1` is even or odd, `n2` is arbitrary, so `n1+n2` need only be integral and can be either even or odd:

```
condition[x_,x0_]=And @@ Reverse @ (Or @@ (n\[Element]Integers/.Simplify[
          Solve[criteria/.n1+n2->n,n][[1]],Assumptions->{x,x0}\[Element]Reals]/.C[1]->0/.#& 
          /@ {n1->1,n1->2}))
```

> $$
> x\neq -\frac{7}{2}\land \text{x0}\neq -\frac{7}{2}\land \left(\frac{\log \left(-\frac{9 (2 \text{x0}+7)}{2 x+7}\right)}{\log (3)}\in \mathbb{Z}\lor \frac{\log \left(\frac{9 (2 \text{x0}+7)}{2 x+7}\right)}{\log (3)}\in \mathbb{Z}\right)
> $$

This condition is sufficient to show the set of points that can be reached is not the real set, e.g. `condition[1,0]` returns `False`, showing `x=1` cannot be reached from `x0=0`.

With this condition, we construct a non-analytic solution, as `f1[x]` for `x` satisfying the condition, and `f2[x]` otherwise:

```
f[x_, x0_] = Piecewise[{{f1[x], condition[x, x0]}}, f2[x]];
```

Testing:

```
ff=FullSimplify[f[f[x,x0],x0],Assumptions->{x,x0}\[Element]Reals]
```

unfortunately gives a long condition for `28+9x` I have to simplify by brute force:

```
(ff[[1,1,2]]/.Log[x_]:>Log[Factor[x]]//PowerExpand//ExpandAll//FullSimplify)/.
(Log[x_]-Log[y_]:>Log[x/y])/.I \[Pi]+Log[x_]->Log[-x]/.
{x_\[Element]Integers->integerQ[x],x_\[NotElement]Integers:>!integerQ[x]}//FullSimplify
```

> True

Comment: I stuck to reals but on hindsight think it's unnecessary. Allowing complex `x` might just amount to 2 criteria, 1 for `n` and another for $c_1$. I have to check with the real assumptions removed though.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @obsolesced, it is simple to find solutions based on any set that is mapped to itself by `f1` and `f2`.  For example, let

```
S = {q1 + q2 Sqrt[2]}  for {q1, q2} rational
```

then

```
f[x] = f1[x]   x in S
f[x] = f2[x]   x not in S
```

satisfies the required functional relation.  It is continuous nowhere (except `x = -7/2`) and `S` is countably infinite and its complement uncountably infinite.

Alternatively, make `S` the Algebraic numbers, then its complement is the Transcendentals - both uncountably infinite.

It would be interesting to know if there are any solutions to the functional equation with `f[x]` not in `{f1[x],f2[x]}`.

Comment: Nice insight, but S is countably infinite no? So much simpler than the minimal set I thought of. I now realize S could have even more simply been all integers or rationals, or even all reals if x is allowed to be complex etc..

Comment: @obsolesced quite right.  I've fixed that and added a better example.

Comment: Unfortunately algebraic numbers are still countable. I'm not sure if it's possible to find S with both S and its complement being uncountable, unless we allow complex x. If it is any consolation, both S and its complement can be dense if S is algebraics or rationals.